# Does Bee Pollen reduce inflammation?

Tags: alternative-medicine, herbalism

There are plenty of sites and people declaring the benefits of Bee Pollen.

A few examples from this site specifically site that the benefits are caused because the pollen will reduce inflammation.  Are there studies that confirm this?

> Skin Soother - Bee pollen is often used in topical products that aim
> to treat inflammatory conditions and common skin irritations like
> psoriasis or eczema. The amino acids and vitamins protect the skin and
> aid the regeneration of cells.
>
> Respiratory System - Bee pollen contains a high quantity of
> antioxidants that may have an anti-inflammatory effect on the tissues
> of the lungs, preventing the onset of asthma.
>
> Prostate Aid - Men who suffer from benign prostate hyperplasia can
> find relief by using bee pollen. Bee pollen can help reduce
> inflammation to stop frequent urges to urinate.

http://foodmatters.tv/articles-1/10-amazing-health-benefits-of-bee-pollen

Comment: webmd claims there's no scientific basis for any health claims: http://www.webmd.com/balance/bee-pollen-benefits-and-side-effects

Comment: I saw that as well, but they don't site any sources

Comment: Bees don't make pollen. They collect it. It's qualities will therefore depend on location & season. A lot of people find that pollen causes inflammation (see Hay-fever).